# Homepage slider disappeared after update

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, slider

All I did was update the extensions

Original: http://test.paperdollpartydress.com/
Updated (broken): http://paperdollpartydress.com/

But none of the extensions seem to pertain to a slider